# What is $0^0$? The zeroth power of zero.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Google](https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=0%5E0&oq=0%5E0&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j6j69i65j69i60j0.4611j0j4&client=ms-android-tecno&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) says the answer is $1$.
[Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0) says it's undefined.

I saw an argument made for $0^0$ being $1$, on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-0-0-the-zeroth-power-of-zero-1/answers/1373648), along the lines of: if you want the binomial theorem to work for real numbers (in the form $(a + 0)^n$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$), then you should accept that $0^0 = 1.$

Comment: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

Comment: If you can't read French, here's an explanation in English: http://oeis.org/wiki/The_special_case_of_zero_to_the_zeroeth_power It includes a few graphs, like $0^x$ and $x^0$, which you might find enlightening.